# Ошибка Rigidbody2D.mass assign attempt for 'CheckBox' is not valid. Input mass is { Infinity }

Tags: c#, unity3d

у меня выдалась ошибка `Rigidbody2D.mass assign attempt for 'CheckBox' is not valid. Input mass is { Infinity }`

вот код:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AllShapesJump : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        rb.mass = 0.7f / Controller.numberOfShapes;
    }
    public void ShapesJump() 
    {
        if (Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.y) < 0.05f)
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(Random.Range(-20f, 20f), 30f), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Comment: @aepot на какой строчке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простая математика, при делении на ноль будет бесконечность (infinity).

```
void Update()
{
    if (Controller.numberOfShapes > 0)
    {
        rb.mass = 0.7f / Controller.numberOfShapes;
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое!!!